# C# mvc data missing in the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code

The website user page is supposed to display user's information include id, name, email, contact and last login time. All the data are displayed well in the web page except contact.

This is user display controller

```
[Authorize]
      public IActionResult Users()
      {
            string userid = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;         
            List<SysUser> list = DBUtl.GetList<SysUser>("SELECT * FROM Investor WHERE InvestorId = '{0}'", userid); //WHERE UserRole = 'member'
         return View(list);
      }
```

This user model

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DDemo.Models
{
    public class SysUser

    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter User ID")]
        [Remote(action: "VerifyUserID", controller: "Account")]
        public string InvestorId { get; set; }

        

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Password")]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Password must be 5 characters or more")]
        public string InvestorPw { get; set; }

        [Compare("InvestorPw", ErrorMessage = "Passwords do not match")]
        public string InvestorPw2 { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Full Name")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Email")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; } //@ sign 

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Contact Number")]
        [RegularExpression(@"\d{8}", ErrorMessage = "Please enter 8 digit number")]
        public string Contact { get; set; }

        public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is view

```
@model List<SysUser>

@if (TempData["Message"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-@TempData["MsgType"]">
        @TempData["Message"]
    </div>
}

<h2>Investors</h2>

<table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Email</th>
        <th scope="col">Contact</th>
        <th scope="col">Last Login</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (SysUser user in Model)
    {
<tr>

    <td>@user.InvestorId</td>
    <td>@user.FullName</td>
    <td>@user.Email</td>
    <td>@user.Contact</td>
    <td>@String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}", user.LastLogin)</td>
    <td>


        <a asp-controller="Account"
           asp-action="UserUpdate"
           asp-route-id="@user.InvestorId">
            Update
        </a>
        <!--|

        <a asp-controller="Account"
           asp-action="Delete"
           asp-route-id="@user.InvestorId"
           onclick="return confirm('Delete User [@user.FullName]')">
            Delete
        </a>-->
    </td>

</tr>
    }
</table>
```

As in the screenshot, other values are correctly displayed except for contact
[image]

Comment: Did you check the data? Is there a value for that userId, also check that Column name is the same property name 'Contact' in the db

Comment: Whats the value of "list" when your actionresult returns?

Comment: Did you debug the code? whats the value in contact field? can you pls tell ? i see there is the validation on contact field, if the value isn't valid the field would remain empty.